# How do I write the copy Constructor for Composition?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, composition

below is my code:

```
class Pulley{
private:
    int noOfTeeth;

public:
    Pulley();
    Pulley(int teeth);
    ~Pulley();

    void show();
};

Pulley::Pulley()
{
    cout << "Pulley constructor called!";
    noOfTeeth = 0;
}

Pulley::Pulley(int teeth)
{
    cout << "Pulley constructor called!";
    noOfTeeth = teeth;
}

void Pulley::show()
{
    cout << "\n\nNo of Teeths of Pulley: " << noOfTeeth;
}

Pulley::~Pulley()
{

}

class GearBox{
    private:
    char *transmission;
    Pulley p;

    public:
    GearBox();
    GearBox(char *trans, int pTeeth);
    ~GearBox();

    void show();
};

GearBox::GearBox(): p()
{
    cout << "Gearbox constructor called!";
    transmission = NULL;
}

GearBox::GearBox(char *trans, int pTeeth): p(pTeeth)
{
    cout << "Gearbox constructor called!";
    if(trans != NULL)
    {
        transmission = new char[strlen(trans)+1];
        strcpy(transmission, trans);
    }
    else
    {
        transmission = NULL;
    }   
}

void GearBox::show()
{
    cout << "\n\nTransmission of vehicle: " << transmission;
    p.show();
}

GearBox::~GearBox()
{

}

class Vehicle{
private:
    char *model;
    char *color;
    GearBox g;

public:
    Vehicle();
    Vehicle(char *mod, char *col, char *gr);
    Vehicle(const Vehicle &vh);
    ~Vehicle();

    void show();
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(): g()
{
    cout << "Vehicle constructor called!";
    model = NULL;
    color = NULL;
}

Vehicle::Vehicle(char *mod, char *col, char *gr): g(gr)
{
    cout << "Vehicle constructor called!";
    if(mod != NULL)
    {
        model = new char[strlen(mod)+1];
        strcpy(model, mod);
    }
    else
    {
        model = NULL;
    }

    if(col != NULL)
    {
        color = new char[strlen(col)+1];
        strcpy(color, col);
    }
    else
    {
        color = NULL;
    }
}

void Vehicle::show()
{
    cout << "\n\nModel of Vehicle: " << model;
    cout << "\n\nColor of Vehicle: " << color;
    g.show();
}

int main()
{
    Pulley p(20);
    GearBox g("Manual", p);
    Vehicle V("Honda", "Black", g);
    V.show();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Now, when I run this code I get a lots of error, I don't know what are those and how to resolve them. The one error I understood is of Copy Constructor, so can anyone explain me that how can I write the copy constructor for pointer to characters `transmission, model and color`. Also tell me how do I resolve other errors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. If you have a lot of errors with this much code, it is because you did not address them as they arose. **Never add to code that doesn't work.** I suggest you simplify this code as much as you can while still getting some errors; you may find that the bugs become obvious, otherwise you can post a simpler example.

Comment: when storing strings, use std::string. Don't write destructors or copy operators. Delegate to std::string, std::vector, std::unique_ptr, etc.

Comment: _Now, when I run this code I get a lots of error, I don't know what are those and how to resolve them._ From this statement it is unclear if you got compilation errors (if so, what are those errors?), or your code failed in runtime (if so, did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to find why it failed?).

Comment: It's very important to understand [the rules of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when implementing constructors, destructors and assignment operators. Following this advice will likely solve your problem.

Comment: @Beta sure, thanks for the advice, I will do the same next time.

Comment: why do you call constructors in main that call constructors that don't match the call?

Comment: @RichardHodges thanks, I will try using string data-type

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes I read the debugger's place where the errors list is shown and I understood the error was of copy-constructor which I did not write and I do not know how to write Copy-Constructor in this case where I am using some objects as sub-objects of main object, in other words where I am applying the Composition.

Comment: @Drt which constructor I called in the main that call constructors that don't match the call?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar  GearBox g("Manual", p);  and:
    Vehicle V("Honda", "Black", g);  I put your code in VS and the problem looks like a constructor call issue.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Pulley{
private:
    int noOfTeeth;

public:
    Pulley(int teeth = 0);

    void show();
};

Pulley::Pulley(int teeth)
: noOfTeeth(teeth)
{
    std::cout << "Pulley constructor called!";
}

void Pulley::show()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nNo of Teeths of Pulley: " << noOfTeeth;
}

class GearBox{
    private:
    std::string transmission;
    Pulley p;

    public:
    GearBox(std::string trans = std::string(), Pulley p = Pulley());

    void show();
};

GearBox::GearBox(std::string trans, Pulley p)
: transmission(std::move(trans))
, p(std::move(p))
{
    std::cout << "Gearbox constructor called!";
}

void GearBox::show()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nTransmission of vehicle: " << transmission;
    p.show();
}

class Vehicle{
private:
    std::string model;
    std::string color;
    GearBox g;

public:
    Vehicle();
    Vehicle(std::string mod = "", std::string col = "", GearBox gr = GearBox());

    void show();
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(std::string mod,std::string col, GearBox gr)
: model(std::move(mod))
, color(std::move(col))
, g(std::move(gr))
{
    std::cout << "Vehicle constructor called!";
}

void Vehicle::show()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nModel of Vehicle: " << model;
    std::cout << "\n\nColor of Vehicle: " << color;
    g.show();
}

int main()
{
    Pulley p(20);
    GearBox g("Manual", p);
    Vehicle V("Honda", "Black", g);
    V.show();
//    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: I would consider this answer incomplete. It doesn't indicate what changes were made nor does it explain the reason behind them.

Comment: Can you do my homework for me without teaching me anything too?

Comment: It was posted to expand upon a comment

Comment: @RichardHodges can you explain the code `move(trans)` and `move(p)`, first of all is `move()` a built-in function if yes then for what purpose do we use it?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar all questions on c++ standard library functions answered here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: @RichardHodges thanks a lot, I understood all the other program, you used standard library names and for that you used `std::` notation, secondly you used data-type `string` instead of using pointers to characters and this reduced the use of copy-constructors plus destructors, thirdly you used `member-initializer-list` in an efficient way, thirdly you initialized the parameters while declaring over-loaded constructors. Thanks a lot, this has helped me and solved my problems. Thanks buddy again :)

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar you're more than welcome.